# JPA Entity not persisted in Spring Boot 3 when only changing List items

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have an Entity called User:

```
import jakarta.persistence.*

import java.util.List;

@Entity(name = "USERS")
public class User {

    private String username;
    private List<String> roles;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USERNAME")
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(final String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Convert(converter = StringListConverter.class)
    @Column(name = "GROUPS")
    public List<String> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(final List<String> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

Before, when using Spring Boot 2.7.9, I could update this entity as follows:

```
public User updateUser(String username, User updatedUser) {
    User user = this.userRepository.findById(username).orElseThrow();
    user.getRoles().removeAll(List.of("user", "admin"));
    user.getRoles().addAll(updatedUser.getRoles());
    return userRepository.save(user);
}
```

But after upgrading to Spring Boot 3, this does not work anymore. I have to create a new ArrayList and call `setRoles()` in order for the entity to be persisted when calling `save()`. So this code *does* work:

```
public User updateUser(String username, User updatedUser) {
    User user = this.userRepository.findById(username).orElseThrow();
    List<String> newRoles = new ArrayList<>(user.getRoles());
    newRoles.removeAll(List.of("user", "admin"));
    newRoles.addAll(updatedUser.getRoles());
    user.setRoles(newRoles);
    return userRepository.save(user);
}
```

There's no exception whatsoever and the `save()` method returns the updated User object (with the updated roles) as expected. But there is no query being executed (according to hibernate logs) and the database is not modified.

Any idea what might cause this?

For completeness, this is the StringListConverter:

```
import jakarta.persistence.AttributeConverter;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class StringListConverter implements AttributeConverter<List<String>, String> {
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(final List<String> strings) {
        return String.join(",", strings);
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> convertToEntityAttribute(final String s) {
        return Arrays.asList(s.split(",")).stream()
                .map(String::trim)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

And this is the UserRepository:

```
@Repository
interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String> {
}
```

Comment: I believe that is known issue: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/HHH/issues/HHH-16081 https://hibernate.atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/HHH/issues/HHH-16147

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Indeed seems like the same issue, so should be fixed in Hibernate 6.2. Thanks.